# Click on Links and Redirect To That Content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a feature where there will be multiple links on the top and contents will be loaded by default with headings in the same page. The links and heading will be related, so clicking on the links, will redirect to that specific divs with an effect (Similar to single page app). Example:

```
Vision Mission Address Contact

Vision
Content here 

Mission
Content here 

Address
Content here 

Contact
Content here
```

I am not sure how I am able to do so but created a sample that isn't actually similar, a trial can be said. This isn't what I want:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $(".subcontent").hide();

  $('#myMenu').on('click','a',function()
  {
    $('.subcontent:visible').hide();
    $('.subcontent[id='+$(this).attr('data-id')+']').fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myMenu">
  <li><a href="#" data-id="Vision">Vision</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-id="Mission">Mission</a></li>
</ul>


<section class="subcontent"  id="Vision" style="display:block" >
  <div class="page-heading">
     <h1 class="caption">Vision</h1>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="subcontent"  id="Mission" >
  <div class="page-heading">
     <h1 class="caption">Mission</h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You are talking about anchors ? [Check this, his `Contents` box work with `anchors`](https://html.com/anchors-links/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope the below snippet helps you

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.top').click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".top-section").offset().top
  }, 1000)
}), 
  $('.middle').click(function (){
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(".middle-section").offset().top
    }, 1000)
  }),
  $('.bottom').click(function (){
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(".bottom-section").offset().top
    }, 1000)
  })
  
 $('.top-section').click(function (){
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 1000)
  })
 $('.middle-section').click(function (){
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 1000)
  })

  $('.bottom-section').click(function (){
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 1000)
  })
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
}

.top-section {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.middle-section {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.bottom-section {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <h4>Click on Top,Middle.Bottom will take to the section,Click on Click on section will take to the Top</h4>
    
    <h5 class="top">Top</h5> 
    <h5 class="middle">Middle</h5> 
    <h5 class="bottom">Bottom</h5>
</div>
<div class="top-section">
    <h1>Top Section</h1>
</div>
<div class="middle-section">
    <h1>Middle Section</h1>
</div>
<div class="bottom-section">
    <h1>Bottom Section</h1>
</div>
```